# VSCode won't Overtype Closing Brackets after Backslash

Tags: visual-studio-code

Normally (specifically in Latex), I will type math blocks beginning with `\(`, then the equation, and end with `\)` (I've grown accustom to typing the closing parenthesis and having it overwrite the one that was automatically placed). However, this feature stopped working the other day so I end up with `\(...\))`.

I haven't changed any settings to make this happen. I tried changing "Auto Closing Overtype" to "always" in the settings, but this didn't help.

Comment: Did it stop after updating VSC to 1.40.0? What happens, if you create a plain new file within VSC ("Untitled-1") and type `()` - does that work? If yes, maybe it has sth to do with a Latex extension you may have installed.

Comment: @JohnArcher just to clarify, it only happens when there's a backslash before the closing bracket. Also, this problem occurs in non-tex files.

Comment: I see now. Hm, not sure whether it is possible to install an older version of VSC, at least you would need another PC or VM. Either way, I guess you should create an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues